# What is the best way to read a JSON file and obtain the values without the invisible characters in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a simple JSON file that I was supposed to use as a configuration file, it contains the default directories for whoever is running the script using their MacBooks:

```
{
  "main_sheet_path": "/Users/jammer/Documents/Studios⁩/⁨CAT/⁨000-WeeklyReports⁩/2020/",
  "reference_sheet_path": "/Users/jammer/Documents/DownloadedFiles/"
}
```

I read the JSON file and obtain the values using this code:

```
with open('reportconfig.json','r') as j:
    config_data = json.load(j)

main_sheet_path = str(config_data.get('main_sheet_path'))
reference_sheet_path = str(config_data.get('reference_sheet_path'))
```

I use the path to check for a source file's existence before doing anything with it:

```
source_file = 'source.xlsx'
source_file = main_sheet_path + filename
if not os.path.isfile(source_file) :
    print ('ERROR: Source file \'' + source_file + '\' NOT FOUND!')
    return
```

Note that the filename is inputted as a parameter when the script is run (there are multiple files, the script has to know which one to target).

The file is there for sure but the script never seems to "see" it so I get that "ERROR" that I printed in the above code. Why do I think there are invisible characters? Because when I copy and paste from what was printed in the "error" notice above into the terminal, the last few characters of the file name always gets substituted by some invisible characters and hitting backspace erases characters where the cursor isn't supposed to be.

How do I know for sure that the file is there and that my problem is with reading the JSON file and not in the Directory names or anywhere else in the code? Because I finally gave up on using a JSON config file and went with a configuration file like this instead:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
file_paths = { "main_sheet_path": "/Users/jammer/Documents/Studios⁩/⁨CAT/⁨000-WeeklyReports⁩/2020/",
               "reference_sheet_path": "/Users/jammer/Documents/DownloadedFiles/"
             }
```

I then just import the file and obtain the values like this:

```
import reportconfig as cfg
main_sheet_path = cfg.file_paths['main_sheet_path']
reference_sheet_path = cfg.file_paths['reference_sheet_path']
...
```

This workaround works perfectly — I don't get the "error" that the file isn't there when it is and the rest of the script is executed as expected. When the file isn't there, I get the proper "error" I expect and copying-and-pasting the full path and filename from the "error message" gives me the complete file name and hitting the backspace erases the right characters (no funny behavior, no invisible characters).

But could anyone please tell me how read the JSON file properly without getting those pesky invisible characters? I've spent hours trying to figure it out including searching seemingly related questions in stackoverflow but couldn't find the answer. TIA!

Comment: Where do you set `filename`?

Comment: `json.load()` won't return any invisible characters unless there are escape sequences in the JSON. The JSON data itself can't contain invisible characters, it won't load correctly.

Comment: Here's a repr of what you posted: `'{\n  "main_sheet_path": "/Users/jammer/Documents/Studios\u2069/\u2068CAT/\u2068000-WeeklyReports\u2069/2020/",\n  "reference_sheet_path": "/Users/jammer/Documents/DownloadedFiles/"\n}'`. The best way would be not to have unneeded characters in your file in the first place. This likely comes from using an editor in Arabic, Hebrew or similar BiDi setting when editing the file.

Comment: @Barmar: You are wrong, U+2068 and U+2069 are definitely not ignored by `json.load` if present in JSON strings. Demo: `repr(json.load(io.StringIO('"->\u2068--\u2069<-"')))` evaluates to `'->\u2068--\u2069<-'`.

Comment: @Barmar In fact, "All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks, except for the characters that MUST be escaped: quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F)."  ([spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#page-9)). The characters bothering OP are none of those.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you. I edited the JSON file in VIM and re-typed the values instead of copying-and-pasting from somewhere. Totally worked. Thank you also for teaching me about repr!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is just a typo error in this code:
   `source_file = 'source.xlsx'
    source_file = main_sheet_path + filename`

Maybe filename is set to some other file which is not present hence it is giving you error.
Try to set `filename='source.xlsx'`

Maybe it will help